# How to add comma separated string into datatable in c#?

Tags: c#

Let's consider I have two comma separated strings as written below.

```
string name = "A,B,C,D";
string value = "100,200,300,400";
```

So I want to split these two strings and want to insert into DataTable which is as shown below.

Name        Value

A         100

B         200

C         300

D         400

Comment: What have you tried (e.g. `string.Split`) and what problems have you run into?

Comment: Hint: Split/Zip/Select or something similar with aggregate ;)

Comment: just split a string, create a datatable with two columns, iterate the splitted string ,add rows into the datatable as you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("value", typeof(string));

string name = "A,B,C,D";
string value = "100,200,300,400";

string[] names = name.Split(',');
string[] values = value.Split(',');

for(int i=0; i<names.Length; i++)
    table.Rows.Add(new object[]{ names[i], values[i] });
```

But you should implement some validation code to make it more
appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

split sourse strings and add to datatable

```
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("value", typeof(string));

    table.Rows.Add("nameStr", "valueStr");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] names = name.split(',');
string[] values = value.split(',');

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("name");
dt.Columns.Add("value");

int cnt = names.length;
for(int i=0; i<cnt; i++)
{
  DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
  dr["name"] = names[i];
  dr["value"] = values[i];
}
```

Comment: This will also work but syntax error is there. That is
Inplace of "string names[]", we need to write "string[] names".
By doing this it is working.
Thanks for your response...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  string[] name = "A,B,C,D".Split(',');
           string[] value = "100,200,300,400".Split(',');
             DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
             tbl.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
             tbl.Columns.Add("value", typeof(string));
            for( int i=0; i<name.Length;i++)
            {

                 tbl.Rows.Add(name[i],value[i]);
            }
```