# binding comma seperated values into a datatable c#

Tags: c#, datatable

My problem is somewhat same as Mentioned in -
[How to add comma separated string into datatable in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519543/how-to-add-comma-separated-string-into-datatable-in-c)

But in my case the number of columns are not fixed.
Where High is the highest value while others are values at different time intervals.

So, I have to show the values till midnight...
Like if user chooses 1 pm i have to show from 1 pm to midnight all values..
So what user choose will vary, they can choose 2pm 4 am so on so the number of columns will vary.

Product Name    High    15:00   14:45   14:30   14:15   14:00   13:45   13:30...
Product1    12  10  10  10  10  10  12  0   n
Product2    10  10  0   0   0   0   0   0   n
Product3    10  10  10  10  10  10  5   5   n

I am able to bind the data in form of comma separate values but how to bind in datatable I am not understanding..

My comma separated values is somewhat like below from 15:45 to midnight in case if we consider user has choosen 15th hour..

Product1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1|

Product2,9.00,1,1,1,9.00,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1|

Comment: The data column has to be set to nullable.  The two inputs you provided are different so I can't tell exactly what you have and I don't know the spacing of the columns.  You have two separate issues.  1) To read values into table.  2) To display the selected range of columns.

Comment: @jdweng data will never be null in given scenario if no data it is 0.

Comment: What is the criteria for reading the CSV.  How can you tell difference between Product1 and Product2 CSV inputs?  These input have no time associated with them so how do you filter these inputs on time?

Comment: i know the series from current time to midnight so when i create csv the values are in same order..
Product Name High 15:00 14:45 14:30 14:15 14:00 13:45 13:30...

Comment: Why are you creating a CSV?  You can go directly from the input values to datatable without using a CSV.  So is your data going from selected time backwards to midnight?  Do you want each results put into a different row or into a different column in the table?

Answer (score 0):

How about code like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication22
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           string[] inputs = {
                     "Product1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1",
                     "Product2,9.00,1,1,1,9.00,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1"
                             };
           List<List<string>> data = new List<List<string>>();
           foreach (string input in inputs)
           {
               List<string> newData = input.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToList();
               data.Add(newData);
           }


           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           int maxRows = data.Select(x => x.Count).Max();
           for(int column  = 0; column < data.Count; column++) 
           {
               dt.Columns.Add(data[column][0], typeof(string));
               dt.Columns[column].AllowDBNull = true;
           }
           for (int row = 0; row < maxRows; row++)
           {
               dt.Rows.Add();
           }

           for (int column = 0; column < data.Count; column++)
           {
               for (int row = 0; row < data[column].Count; row++)
               {
                   dt.Rows[row][column] = data[column][row];
               }
           }


        }

    }

}
```