# Stored Procedure for inserting text field values that is created dynamically to the same id using asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, webforms

Im new to ASP.net webforms.Im having a event page,in which i have a field to add sales channel heads mail id.when i click on the plus button i will be able to add more than one sales channels head.

[image]

For inserting the form values into the database im using Stored procedure.and its inserting the records with one sales channel head email id.

I want to know how i can write a stored procedure for inserting dynamic textbox values  into sql server for the same record(That is the id and event name should be same).

This is my stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPInsertEvent
   @eventName varchar(200),
   @eventDate date,
   @costPerHead varchar(200),
   @totalCost varchar(200),
   @salesChannelHeads varchar(200),
   @salesManagers varchar(200),
   @eventCreationTime datetime
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON
-- Insert statements for procedure here
   INSERT INTO dbo.hp_event
   (event_name, event_date, cost_per_head, total_cost, sales_channel_head,    sales_manager,    event_creation_time)
   VALUES
   (@eventName, @eventDate, @costPerHead, @totalCost, @salesChannelHeads, @salesManagers, @eventCreationTime)
END
```

This is my ASP.net function

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SPInsertEvent", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EventName", txtEventName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EventDate", Convert.ToDateTime(txtEventDate.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CostPerHead", txtTotCostPerHead.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TotalCost", txtTotalCostEvent.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SalesChannelHead", txtSalesChannelHead.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SalesManager", txtSalesManagers.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EventCreationTime", DateTime.Now);
conn.Open();
int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (k != 0)
{
  string message = "Event added successfully.";
  string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
  script += message;
  script += "')};";
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessMessage", script, true);
}
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Side question. You have the parameters `@salesChannelHeads` and `@salesManagers`. The names are plural, yet you are inserting it as a single row; which *implies* a denormalised design.

Comment: Side note, I suggest you [avoid AddWithValue](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), although this isn't a major issue with a stored procedure call.

Comment: @Larnu Hi salesChannelHeads and salesManagers are two different fields.i will be having multiple salesChannelHeads mail id,for that i have given the plus button to add more text boxes for Sales Channel Heads.

Comment: @DanGuzman im new to this , i will change that part to parameters.my question is how i can insert the values using stored procedures.

Comment: Side question - why is everything a string in your mind? totalCost and costPerHead sound very much like numeric values. Columns with names like "Id" are often int. Regardless, Erland has much useful information about using ["arrays" in tsql](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) as well as using [TVPs](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html). Still not clear what your goal is but these are likely good places to start.

Comment: @SMor its because,the input fields will be accepting text characters,to do all the math calculations i can just type cast it into int. What i need is a stored procedure for inserting saleschannel heads email id(txtSalesChannelHead,txtSalesChannelHead1,txtSalesChannelHead2) into the sql server table with same id,that is there will be duplicate rows in the table .

Comment: Your question does not tell on how the email ids will be added? comma separated list or separate ids every time you click the "+" something like again opening the text box? If they are separate why can't store them in separate table and reference the EventName?

Comment: @mahesh_b it will be seperate ids ,im quite new to this.storing them in a seperate table means ,creating a temp table and storing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing all the list of email ids for the given event in one table, I would suggest you to store them in `separate` table and you can reference them from the hp_event table whenever you need. So your database design should be some thing like below where `eventid` of `hp_eventSalesManagers` references `eventId` of `hp_event` -

[image]

To make this design work you can make use of [`Table Valued Parameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters) in ADO.NET and follow the below steps:

1. Create a [`User Defined Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) -

   ```
     CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ChannelHeads] As Table
     (    
       EmailIds VARCHAR(50)
     )
   ```
2. Whenever you click button populate a new Data Table(I am using Session to keep track 
   of the previous data), below is the `sample` code:

   ```
      protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           if (Session["DataTable"] == null)
           {
               dataTable = new DataTable();
               dataTable.Columns.Add("EmailIds", typeof(string));
               Session.Add("DataTable", dataTable);
           }
           else
           {
               //If yes then get it from current session
               dataTable = (DataTable)Session["DataTable"];
           }

           DataRow dt_row;
           dt_row = dataTable.NewRow();
           dt_row["EmailIds"] = name.Text;
           dataTable.Rows.Add(dt_row);
       }
   ```
3. When submitting to data base add the below parameter(See the way I am passing the data table to DB):

   ```
      SqlParameter parameterSalesChannelHeads = new SqlParameter();
      parameterSalesChannelHeads.ParameterName = "@salesChannelHeads";
      parameterSalesChannelHeads.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured;
      parameterSalesChannelHeads.Value = (DataTable)Session["DataTable"];
      parameterSalesChannelHeads.TypeName = "dbo.ChannelHeads";
      cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterSalesChannelHeads);
   ```

   *Change all your parameters* in above format just to make sure you are using 
   `Parameters.Add` instead of `Parameters.AddWithValue` as mentioned [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263536/addwithvalue-sql-injection-safe-why/21263687#21263687)
4. Finally change the procedure as below to populate the tables, `below is one of the way`, 
   you can enable error handling and improve the code:

   ```
     ALTER PROCEDURE SPInsertEvent
       @eventName varchar(200),
       @eventDate datetime,
       @costPerHead varchar(200),
       @totalCost varchar(200),
       @salesChannelHeads As [dbo].[ChannelHeads] Readonly,
       @salesManagers varchar(200),
       @eventCreationTime datetime
    AS
     BEGIN 
     SET NOCOUNT ON
     DECLARE @eventID INT

     -- Insert statements for procedure here
     INSERT INTO dbo.hp_event
     (event_name, eventDate, costPerHead, totalCost, eventCreationTime, 
     salesManagers)
     VALUES
     (@eventName, @eventDate, @costPerHead, @totalCost,@eventCreationTime, 
     @salesManagers)

     SET @eventID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

     INSERT INTO dbo.hp_eventSalesManagers
      (eventid,event_name,salesChannelHeads)
     SELECT @eventID, @eventName, EmailIds
      FROM 
      @salesChannelHeads 

   END
   ```

***Finally change the data types of the fields accordingly as mentioned in the comment section for better clarity and usages.***

Comment: Thank you mahesh for the detailed explanation.

Comment: i have one more doubt,what if im using comma separated values?i have seen that ,need to create a splitstring function first and i need to call that function,but im quite confused how and where to call the splitstring function.Could you please help me out.

Comment: You need not to create new split string function. Use the existing split function on ',' charecter and add each one of them in datatable before calling procedure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519543/how-to-add-comma-separated-string-into-datatable-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You said in the comments "What i need is a stored procedure for inserting saleschannel heads email id(txtSalesChannelHead,txtSalesChannelHead1,txtSalesChannelHead2) into the sql server table with same id,that is there will be duplicate rows in the table". Handling a dynamic number of inputs like that is not best done in a stored procedure, from what i can see of your scenario. The easier way is to run the insert procedure from your .NET code once for each textbox. Now I don't know how your textboxes are being added, so I can't tell you how to get the set of textbox values, but once you have it, a simple foreach loop will let you run the stored procedure once for each of them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.So what you are saying is if more than one SalesChannelHeads MailId is there,i should put that inside a forloop?

Comment: Yep, if you have more than 1 textbox, just loop through them and run the procedure once for each saleschannelhead.