# Pass GUID into stored procedure method C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am mostly new to c# so i am looking for some guidance here. I am testing a method that i need to pass a list of guids to and run a stored procedure that returns values based on the guids i pass to it which i can then print to the console. I can get the method to work when i pass only one guid but when i pass a list of guids it seems to not work.

I feel like i am lacking some understanding here around how i should pass the list of guids and return it. I get conversion errors trying to return List.

Here is how far i have got but i feel like i am stuck now and cant progress anymore from any info i have found online.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Guid> tempguid = new List<Guid>();
        tempguid.Add(Guid.Parse("472USFA0-B705-9A73-ABD4-3B1870AF1409"));
        tempguid.Add(Guid.Parse("FA97E6BB-0875-5UB9-967A-87ECC396F9F0"));

        GetValue(tempguid);
        Console.WriteLine(GetValue);
    }

    public void GetValue(List<Guid> tempguid)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("stored procedure here", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", tempguid));

            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine((string)rdr["value"]);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Should i be passing the list like this GetValue(List tempguid)?

**EDIT**

ok so if i use a TVP.

Something like:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Identity] AS TABLE(

[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
)
GO
```

Then my procedure will look something along the lines of:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[procedure_name]
@id dbo.Identity READONLY
as
SELECT t.[id]
      ,t.[value]
  FROM [dbo].[table1] t
  Inner Join @id i on i.Id = t.id
```

How do i use this TVP in c# for my stored procedure?

Comment: One way is to use TVP - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters for passing multiple values to stored procedure. and an example here  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62301581/stored-procedure-for-inserting-text-field-values-that-is-created-dynamically-to/62343734#62343734

Comment: What does the stored procedure look like (not the procedure itself (if it's complicated), but mostly the CREATE and parameters part).  As @mahesh_b has noted, you likely want to pass a table valued parameter.

Comment: @Flydog57 the only parameter in the stored procedure is id

Comment: And, the ID is typed as ... ?

Comment: Hey, @Flydog57 i just made an edit to my question use a TVP. How do i then use this to pass the guid list in c#?

Comment: Did you look at the links in @mahesh_b's comment?

Comment: @Ryan Gadsdon I also debugged your code seems that the guid you shown invalid as they have non-hexadecimal values. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

you need a foreach loop on GUID list. Try like:

```
foreach (var g in tempguid)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", g));
    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
       while (rdr.Read())
       {
          Console.WriteLine((string)rdr["value"]);
       }
       Console.ReadLine();
    }
    cmd.Parameteres.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a list to sp. You need to convert your guids into a csv string example:

```
var param = string.Join(", ", tempguid);
```

Then

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", param));
```

Then after receiving your parameter on the sp pass into [String_Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Goodluck!

Comment: You can pass a list - as a table valued parameter. If you are going to modify the procedure anyway, may as well do it right as opposed to splitting strings.

Answer (score 0):

Passing values to [`TVPs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters) from ADO .NET is very straightforward, and requires very little extra code compared to passing data to regular parameters.

- For the data type you specify SqlDbType.Structured.
- You specify the name of the table type in the TypeName property of the parameter.
- You set the Value property of the parameter to something suitable.

As mentioned in the above link `System.Data.SqlClient` supports populating table-valued parameters from `DataTable`, `DbDataReader` or `IEnumerable<T> \ SqlDataRecord` objects.

If you already have the list of Guids coming from other sources in your case `tempguid` then you could use a [`datatable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netcore-3.1) to pass the details to stored procedure.

```
DataTable tvp = new DataTable();
tvp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id", typeof(Guid)));

// populate DataTable from your List here
foreach (var id in tempguid)
   tvp.Rows.Add(id);
```

And change the ADO.NET code like below -

```
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.tvpProcedure", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter tvpParameter = new SqlParameter();
tvpParameter.ParameterName = "@id";
tvpParameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured;
tvpParameter.Value = tvp;
tvpParameter.TypeName = "dbo.testTVP";
cmd.Parameters.Add(tvpParameter);

 using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
     while (rdr.Read())
      {
        Console.WriteLine((string)rdr["value"]);
      }
       Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

***Side notes:***

- Looks like the `GUIDs` you have shown in the code seems invalid as they contain non-
  hexadecimal values.

  ```
  472USFA0-B705-9A73-ABD4-3B1870AF1409
     ^^
  FA97E6BB-0875-5UB9-967A-87ECC396F9F0
                 ^
  ```
- Change the Type name something meaningful instead of `dbo.Identity` in my case I used
  dbo.testTVP

*Further information* -

http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html

Comment: Yes, this is helpful thank you. My main other question though is how do i pass the list into a method that then returns the stored procedure results.

Comment: You are already passing the list to the method -  GetValue(tempguid);
Console.WriteLine(GetValue);, But your console is printing method name so change the two lines as Console.WriteLine(GetValue(tempguid)); Or jus call the method as the method is printing values.Hope this is what you are referring to!

Comment: Console.WriteLine(GetValue); this not needed at all!

Comment: yes, sorry i worked this all out now. thanks for the help

Comment: Glad if the answer helped you:)